# How do i use the sapply() function on only quantitative variables in dataset?

Tags: r, mean, na, sapply

I am trying compute the mean, median, min, max, and standard deviation for each of the quantitative
variables in the dataset as there are some categorical. However, I know  na.rm = TRUE has to be used, but an error keeps occurring.

```
sapply(data, function(x) c("Stand dev" = sd(x, na.rm =TRUE), 
                         "Mean"= mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                         "Median" = median(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                         "Minimum" = min(x, na.rm =TRUE),
                         "Maximun" = max(x, na.rm =TRUE)))
```

The error:

> ```
> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
> Warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
> Warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
> Warning: argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> ```

Comment: The **purrr** package has a nice function `map_if` for such a situation.

Comment: *In general*, using `sapply` is not recommended since it will silently coerce the result to a different type based on the concrete input. Prefer using `lapply`, `vapply` or, indeed, functions from the ‘purrr’ package.

Comment: Another point: it does not make sense to quote the names of parameters, and it is very misleading: *these are not strings!* R silently treats them as variable names despite the quotes, for historical reasons. Remove the quotes. And, if you want to use spaces in variable names, use backticks (instead of quotes) around the variable names.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But the quotes are nice for the syntax highlighting in RStudio :)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent … in that they reinforce the false impression that these names are strings? Yeah I guess so.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `x <- c(a=1, b=2)` then ```x[`a`]``` does not work.

Comment: Are you trolling?! I trust that you know that R requires different types in different contexts. You also can’t write ``get(`a`)``. Does this mean you define names with quotes? `"a" = 1`? I surely hope not.

Comment: @KonradRudolph *You* are trolling ;-) Anyway I'll use backticks when they will be syntax-highlighted in RStudio ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent They *are* already correctly syntax highlighted: as names. Because that’s what they are. If you don’t like the built-in syntax highlighting of variable names you can adjust the colour scheme. — Your comment seemingly keeps conflating strings and names. So let me reiterate: despite the misleading syntax highlighting, parameter names in R, even when they are quoted, are *not* strings. The quotes (and the syntax highlighting) are *actively lying to you*. In case you don’t believe me: run `identical(quote(c(a = 1)), quote(c("a" = 1)))`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph A `numeric` and a `logical` are highlighted with the same color in RStudio. As well as a `function` and a `character`. Is it a lie too? (trolling)

Answer (score 1):

Please check an example with `mtcars` and `map_if` as below

```r
df <- do.call(cbind, map_if(mtcars, is.numeric, ~ list(mean(.x), median(.x)))) %>% 
as_tibble() %>% unnest(cols = everything())
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  20.1  6.19  231.  147.  3.60  3.22  17.8 0.438 0.406  3.69  2.81
2  19.2  6     196.  123   3.70  3.32  17.7 0     0      4     2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a solution based on `sapply`, you can use this:

```r
sapply(iris[sapply(iris, is.numeric)], 
       function(x) c("Stand dev" = sd(x, na.rm =TRUE), 
                       "Mean"= mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),
                       "Median" = median(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                       "Minimum" = min(x, na.rm =TRUE),
                       "Maximun" = max(x, na.rm =TRUE)))
#>           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> Stand dev    0.8280661   0.4358663     1.765298   0.7622377
#> Mean         5.8433333   3.0573333     3.758000   1.1993333
#> Median       5.8000000   3.0000000     4.350000   1.3000000
#> Minimum      4.3000000   2.0000000     1.000000   0.1000000
#> Maximun      7.9000000   4.4000000     6.900000   2.5000000
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, as noted above, a solution using `dplyr` may be more convenient:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
iris |> 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), 
                   list(`Stand dev` = sd,
                        Mean = mean,
                        Median = median,
                        Minimum = min,
                        Maximum = max), na.rm=TRUE))
#>   Sepal.Length_Stand dev Sepal.Length_Mean Sepal.Length_Median
#> 1              0.8280661          5.843333                 5.8
#>   Sepal.Length_Minimum Sepal.Length_Maximum Sepal.Width_Stand dev
#> 1                  4.3                  7.9             0.4358663
#>   Sepal.Width_Mean Sepal.Width_Median Sepal.Width_Minimum Sepal.Width_Maximum
#> 1         3.057333                  3                   2                 4.4
#>   Petal.Length_Stand dev Petal.Length_Mean Petal.Length_Median
#> 1               1.765298             3.758                4.35
#>   Petal.Length_Minimum Petal.Length_Maximum Petal.Width_Stand dev
#> 1                    1                  6.9             0.7622377
#>   Petal.Width_Mean Petal.Width_Median Petal.Width_Minimum Petal.Width_Maximum
#> 1         1.199333                1.3                 0.1                 2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>